# How do I add a header into Google's new NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigationview

I'm trying to add my own custom header view into Google's new `NavigationView` but for some reason, no matter what I do, Android Studio gives me a warning saying `include` and `RelativeLayout` is not allowed here. I tried doing

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/nav_drawer_header" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccc"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

but only the `RecyclerView` shows up and I'm not sure what else to do.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add headers to a `NavigationView` using the `app:headerLayout` XML attribute:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header" />
```

Or programatically via [inflateHeaderView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateHeaderView(int))

Answer (score 0):

Below demonstrates a typical usage of **NavigationView** in the Design Support Library. As you can see, the NavigationView have an attribute called **headerLayout** to set its header view.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!-- Content -->
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <!-- Drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>    
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I would have done this but the menu I'm using is dynamic and I was already using `RecyclerView` with the old set up for Navigation Drawer, so I wanted to stick with that.